# Any libraries for parsing HTML in Windows phone 7?

Tags: c#, html, silverlight-4.0, windows-phone-7.1

I am looking for a good HTML parser for Windows Phone 7 in C#. HTMLAgilityPack is giving some problems with Windows Phone 7. Please reply.

Answer (score 1):

Here are 2 libraries for parsing HTML in C#...

- [HTMLAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)
- [Majestic-12 HTML parser](http://www.majestic12.co.uk/projects/html_parser.php)